# In Chrome, what's the simplest way to view the mime type of a document?

Tags: html, google-chrome, mime-types

In Firefox, you can select "View Page Info" from the right-click menu, and the mime type will be displayed.

But the same "View Page Info" command in Chrome does not show the mime type.

Feels like I'm overlooking something obvious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hit `F12` and then go to Network tab. If you want html document then narrow the filter to Documents (on the bottom).

Comment: I am unable to see the mime-type/content-type which is used in chrome in the network tab.

Comment: Network tab must be open before page load and in documents category of network tab it shows enumerated document type instead of mime type. Thus this is not a correct answer.

Comment: I do not see mime-type or content-type in the Network tab. I see the **Type** column but these say things like "document" or "stylesheet" which is not what i'm looking for. (I'm looking for something like "text/css"). A screenshot would be very helpful.

Comment: @chharvey after selecting the **Network** tab, select the name of the resource, then hit the **Headers** tab. Under **Response Headers** find **Content-Type**. With images you can select the **Preview** tab and you will be able to the some information about the resource including the mime type located at the bottom of the developer window.

Comment: @Prancer Thanks! Very helpful. You should provide this info in your own separate answer.

Comment: Just to update this answer now, with version 55.0.2883.87 of chrome, you need to add `Content-Type` in the "Response Headers" > "Manage Header Columns" > "Add custom header" menu. it is not exposed by default in the network tab anymore. Hope this helps others in future!

Answer (score 25):

*Earlier & later versions of Chrome may be slightly different*

**Chrome v50.0.2661.102 m**

To open Chromes developer tools (*several options*):

1. Menu -> More Tools -> Developer Tools
2. `Ctrl + Shift + I`
3. Hit the
   `F12` key

Once open, select the **Network** tab, select the name of the resource on the lefthand side, then hit the **Headers** tab. Under **Response Headers** find **Content-Type** which is your mime type.

[image]

With images you can select the **Preview** tab and you will be able to see some information about the resource, including the mime type, located at the bottom of the developer window.

[image]

Comment: This method fails when Chrome loads the resource directly from the local file system (under a ‘file’ scheme, that is), because then it omits the _Response Headers_ section. Yet the Firefox method cited by the OP (context menu item _View page info_) works regardless of scheme.