# @RequestBody not mapping JSON to Java Object - Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, mapping, spring-restcontroller

I am unable to convert my JSON from post's method body into my POJO, with `@RequestBody` inside my controller class.

I debugged the error and I saw that certain fields were mapped and others were not. Like this **(POJO)**:

`name: null, typeOfPlan: null, Email: example@gmail.com, PhoneNum: 123456789, Website: test.org, Username: null, password: 1234`, which is strange.

**JSON:**

```
{
    "confirmPassword": "1234",
    "email": "example@gmail.com",
    "password": "1234",
    "phoneNum": "123456789",
    "name": "Hello world",
    "typeOfPlan": "Test",
    "userName": "user",
    "website": "test.org"
}
```

**Controller**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SomeController {

    @Autowired
    private Service foo;

    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(value = "/create")
    private void createAccount(@RequestBody BigFoo bigFoo) {
        foo.createAccount(bigFoo);
    }
}
```

From here, I call my service, then DAO classes.

**POJO**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BigFoo {

    private String name;
    private String typeOfPlan;
    private String email;
    private String website;
    private String phoneNum;
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

---

I have also tried to allow JSON with `consumes media type` in the `@PostMapping`, but it failed it solve this.

Using Jackson ObjectMapper did not work as well.

Comment: You didn't include the actual JSON content.

Comment: Give me one second. EDIT: I added the exact format which they appear in my Object in debug mode. Sorry, it's my POJO, not JSON.

Comment: share the JSON to understand better

Comment: I added the JSON

Comment: Try adding the gettter and setter method or use lombok.

Comment: I will try lombok, as I never used it before.

Comment: It has the same result, I will add lombok to my question though.

Comment: In your Json you posted Strings should be wrapped in double quotes. e.g. "confirmPassword": "1234". validate your Json https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @user1697575 It is valid JSON, I would put a screenshot here, but I cannot.

Comment: I have the same issue as you @Compilerv2, but this time what is strange is that my POJO variables and my frontend is spelt exactly the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My problem was simple:** my variables in my Angular project, sending the data to my Spring Boot app were misspelled, and therefore were not recognized by my backend application and hence, were not mapped to my POJO correctly.

---

After I changed my frontend form variables to match my POJO's variables, I got this:

**POJO data**

`name: It's good now, typeOfPlan: 2 Year, Email: example@gmail.com, PhoneNum: 123456789, Website: test.org, Username: Master, password: 1234`

Spring Boot was unable to map `name`, `typeOfPlan` & `Username` from the JSON because they simply did not match the ones in my backend.

---

**Before**

`Name, typeOfPlan, userName`

**After**

`name, type, username`

Thanks all!

Comment: I actually had the same issue, and I can't believe I didn't spot it. I had "password" with 3 's'es in my request and my eyes just couldn't see it: "passsword". I'm glad you posted this, because it made me go back and double-check.

Answer (score 0):

First, If you are using `Postman, curl etc..` try to send the json that way:

```
{
    "confirmPassword": "1234",
    "email": "example@gmail.com",
    "password": "1234",
    "phoneNum": "123456789",
    "name": "Hello world",
    "typeOfPlan": "Test",
    "userName": "user",
    "website": "test.org"
}
```

Second, the only null value I'm getting is `username`, because you are sending it in your json like that: `userName`, You should check that your json compatible with your `POJO`

Comment: No, I am not using Postman or Curl. I am sending it directly from my frontend Angular project.

Comment: I wasn't sending my JSON with a null value, I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: I meant the that userName have  a capital N inside and because of the it didnt worked

Comment: I see, but I got the JSON from my chrome inspector that outputs the `console.log()`. So it shouldn't really affect my JSON, because it is just a representation the JSON. I never touched it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with content-type! set it to `application/json`. Specify it in postman or curl.

if you send it with js try this example

```
axios.post(
                "/rest/yoururl",
                jsObject
            ).then(
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                }.bind(this)
            );
```

by default content-type is json

by curl:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' \
  http://url
```

In postMan:

> Headers-> put key Content-Type -> value application/json. If you are
>   in postman

Comment: Where do I find `content-type` so I can set it to `application/json`?

Comment: Headers-> put key `Content-Type` -> value `application/json`. If you are in postman

Comment: I am clueless where to put it in my project, again I don't have postman nor Curl, or any other app that deals with what you are saying. I sent the JSON manually by typing into the form from my frontend project and submitted it.

Comment: ops, that is problem. Check what is Content-type in browser then

Comment: Where is that in my browser? I cannot find it as said here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148497/in-chrome-whats-the-simplest-way-to-view-the-mime-type-of-a-document I am looking at my network tab in the inspector.

Comment: in chrome:
right mouse click -> inspect element -> network tab ->
when you press a button on your form, some request will be sent and will apear in  log -> click on it -> look at its headers -> done

Comment: I think you need to read something about content types, to be able to use it in your work. It is okey that you aren't front-end developer, but you write code to be used by front-end, and you need to know how it can transmit data to the server, and actually there are only couple popular content-types, you will easily remember them (some are used by default in forms, others used by default when you make ajax request with specific method). 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the data wrapped in brackets like this - {data}. It's nice to double check the structure well whether it is an array or an object.